# Laravel, view to PDF using DomPDF

Tags: laravel, pdf

**Scenario**: I am currently trying to convert a Laravel view to pdf so that the user can have a pdf version of their profile page.

**Info**: I am using Laravel cashier which apparently comes with dompdf to create invoices. I found this out when trying to do

> composer require dompdf/dompdf

. The Error message was

> laravel/cashier v6.0.18 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.6.1 -> satisfiable
>   by dompdf/dompdf[v0.6.1, v0.6.2] but these conflict with your
>   requirements or minimum-stability

Also found out from the Laravel cashier documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/billing#generating-invoice-pdfs

So I am using dompdf v0.6 I imagine.

**Problem**: I try using dompdf as normal since I think I have it setup from Laravel cashier. But I am getting many errors in my controller when trying to use any functionality from dompdf, if I try:

```
use Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```

I get an error saying that class Dompdf is not defined. so If I try to use Laravel cashier functionality for their "pdf conversion for invoices" like so:

```
$pdf = downloadInvoice::loadView('dashboard.index', ['user' => $user]);
    return $pdf->download('profile.pdf');
```

Then I get an error saying that

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\downloadInvoice' not found

I tried Googling a lot but I am really lost at this point, can someone be so kind to point a lost developer in the right direction? :) Thank you for your time in advnaced!

**EDIT**: I tried:

`$pdf = PDF::loadView('dashboard.index', ['user' => $user]);
    return $pdf->download('profile.pdf');`

but get

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\PDF' not found

It looks like dompdf is not even being reconginzed. Is there a away I can look into this and see if this thing is working properly?

Comment: I dont have a file named 'downloadInvoice.php'.  I have a blade file named index.blade.php that I am trying to convert to pdf. This file is located in the resources/views/dashboard/ directory. Thank you for the correction on the command!! :). Sorry not sure what I provided helps any.

Comment: Replace class reference line with `use Dompdf\Dompdf;`

Comment: Anyone leaving a down vote please explain to me why it receives a downvote so that I can correct my question.

Answer (score 0):

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\downloadInvoice' not found

It looks that your `downloadInvoice.php` is located in other folder and/or using different namespace, so you simply miss proper `use` (if you are using PHPStorm, simply put cursor next to `downloadInvoice::` and hit <kbd>CTRL+ENTER</kbd>.

In some cases you may also need to do `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: I did the composer dumpautoload. Didnt seem to fix any current error messages. I am using phpstorm so I went and did ctrl+enter on the downloadInvoice but it does not do anything, It is still highlighting it saying undefined class, and when clicking on the lightbulb to import a class it only gives me the option to create a class and not import anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I tried doing this instead from another stackoverflow post ''$pdf = pdf::loadView('dashboard.index', ['user' => $user]);
    return $pdf->download('profile.pdf');" just as a normal dompdf function but it seems like dompdf is not even being recognized but looks to be installed. Any suggestions on what I can do to look into this?

Comment: I am almost 1oo percent sure you either lack some `use` or miss `namespace`

Comment: I think you guys are correct on this :). I am going through the steps that @AddWeb has shown me. I will keep you guys updated with my findings after i complete the steps outlined in the guide :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Quick start documentation](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#quick-start), code should look like:

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;  <-- May this is the mistake

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();
```

Let me know if still this not work for you.

Comment: As instructed I put 'use Dompdf\Dompdf;' near my other imports or uses in my controller then replaced the things in my public function index() with // instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();

and get Class 'Dompdf\Dompdf' not found. Then I tried to use Dompdf; instead and it says multiple definitions exist, which I think is good.

Comment: Then I get Class 'Dompdf' not found. So weird. Thank you for your guys feedback, i think we can get to the bottom of this with everyones help on here :)

Comment: Might be a namespace problem, hope the solution is in your given exception but you need to check that. I expect that you check configuration step by step,  and I hope you get the result as success.

Comment: Thank you, I dont know how to proceed to check this but I will continue to research :)

Comment: No need to research just go through [Easy Installation guide](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#easy-installation). You can also get some code example help from [here](https://dompdf.net/examples.php). Best Of Luck!

Comment: Thank you, I will go through this :). do you know where I put this? The site says: 
Make sure that the autoload file from Composer is loaded.

// somewhere early in your project's loading, require the Composer autoloader
// see: http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: Check this straightforward [L5 package documentation](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/0.5) which is directly point to L5, so you can install and use it with followed by few steps.